# Is there one word that means female car enthusiast?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms, feminine

There are words like *gear head*, *speedophile*, *car nut* etc. that are all gender neutral, however, I am creating a support group or a common interest linkup for women who have a passion for cars.
I am looking for a name for this group and would like to denote the feminine aspect of it.
I have thought using unicorn in the name, as rare cars and car chicks are often referred to as unicorns, due to their rarity, but I'd like the name to stand on its own without having to be explained. So, if there is a word that means female car enthusiast, it would be helpful. Or help me create a new word... :)

Comment: I have heard **Gearhead Girls** used to describe a female group before.

Comment: http://feministing.com/2009/06/08/the_adventures_of_a_female_gea/

Comment: Not a single word, but as ICE is a common acronym for the internal combustion engine, how about ICE Maidens?!

Comment: _The Gearhettes_? Pronounced almost identical to _gearheads_, but incorporates the feminine-group-suffix _-ettes_.

Comment: I think the simple answer is that there is not my word for this with any great backing but that there are myriad neologisms, some of which have a nice ring to them.

Comment: Welvome to EL&U. Requests for names are off-topic, which I think is the reason this question has attracted closevotes. For what it's worth, I don't think any such term is established. When Mary Barra was announced as GM's CEO, the excitement was not just that she was female, but that she was a (wait for it…) "[woman car guy](http://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2013/12/gms-first-female-ceo-is-a-car-guy/282224/)."

Comment: Car aficionada?